# Testing Angularjs application that are bootstrap manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

i have problem with testing angularjs application (karma, jasmine) when bootstrap application manually in code after some http ajax requests.

```
angular.module("app", []);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});
```

I also have following code in my jasmine specs

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

And when i run my specs i always have the same error

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to laod it ....
```

Is there a way for waiting for angular bootstrap application in beforeEach function?

Comment: Do you definitely have the module loaded in you Karma configuration file? Manual bootstrap has no effect on unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is caused by having your bootstrap code included in the karma config.  I was having the same issue.

I took the bootstrap code:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});
```

and moved it into its own js file called bootstrap.js.  Then in my index.html I put the script tag for this at the bottom of the page (after the script where I declare my app module).

```
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I made sure that bootstrap.js was not included in my karma config and now my tests pass.

The reason karma was failing was because it does not need the bootstrap code to run and the bootstrap code was getting run by karma in way that it fails to initialize the app.